# Dynamic links within a GridView in ASP.net/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, mailto

I'm trying to create a GridView on  page which lists the administrators for a system and there email address.

I would like to make it so that the administrators email address is displayed as a `mail-to` link.

At the moment I have got that working however the browser keeps trying to open the `mail-to` address as if its a web address and of course returns a 404 error.

Is there a way to stop the browser redirecting to the `mail-to` address?

I am using a hyperlink as an item template in the asp definition of the GridView, like this :

```
<asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("E-mail") %>' 
    NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("E-mail", "mailto:{0}") %>' Target=""></asp:HyperLink>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

As I mentioned previously, the code does generate the `mail-to` link as expected but the browser keeps trying to redirect to it and I would like it not to do that and just stay on the same page instead.

Obviously I am using ASP.net and C# for this project.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below, may be it will help you...

```
NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("mailto:{0}", Eval("E-mail"))%>'
```